# Django URL with arguments pointing to the same page using "with as template"?

Tags: python, django

This is the weirdest problem I have ever come across. Here is it:

URLS.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'discussions'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>Q[0-9]+)$', views.question, name='question'),
]
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'discussions/discussion.html',
                  {"questions": Question.objects.all(), "activities": Activity.objects.all()[:10]})
#details for this function question are not neccessary but still I have added them.
def question(request, question_id):
    question_id = int(question_id[1:])
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    related = []
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(QID=question)
    for q in questions:
        score = (similar(q.title, question.title))
        if score > 0.3 and score != 1:
            related.append(q)
    votes = Vote.objects.filter(username=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)).filter(
        Q(QID=question_id) | Q(AID__in=Answer.objects.filter(QID=question_id).values_list('id', flat=True)))
    return render(request, 'discussions/question.html',
                  {"question": question, "votes": votes, "related": related, "answers": answers,
                   "activities": Activity.objects.all()[:7], "form": AnswerForm()})
```

Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200 , default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1055, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=None)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

discussion.html

```
{% for question in questions|dictsortreversed:"votes" %}
     <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="asked by {{ question.username }} on {{ question.date }} has {{ question.count }} answers">
        <a href="{% url 'discussions:question'  with 'Q'|add:question.id as template %}" style="color: black"><h5>{{ question.id }}{{ question.title }}</h5></a>
        <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill bg-{% if question.votes >= 0 %}success{% else %}danger{% endif %}">{{ question.votes }}</span>
     </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the thing is in discussion.html on each question I want it to redirect it to its own question page which looks something like, website.come/discussion/Q5. Here 5 is the {{question.id}}. Now whenever I hover the mouse on the link, I am only redirected to the same page that is website.com/discussions

And the weirdest thing about this is that, whenever I open the page question.html, the all these things are working fine, the same code which is written in discussions.html works on that page!

**How is it possible that I am doing same thing on both the templates and getting weird and irritating results?**

Please feel free to ask me any extra information in the comments.

**EDIT 1** However, if I change the URL pattern to

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$', views.question, name='question'),
```

And change discussion.html link to:

```
<a href="{% url 'discussions:question' question.id %}" style="color: black"><h5>{{ question.title }}</h5></a>
```

Everything works perfectly and I m redirected to website.come/discussions/5

Comment: I don't understand why you are using that `as template` at all. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, {{ question.id }} returns me 5 (id of that question,for example), so I am just concatenating it with Q so that the url becomes website.com/discussions/Q5 , I want to separate this from the id's of answers which will be similar but A5. Therefore, I am doing this concatenation of Q with the question.id . Also my url pattern matches with discussion/Q5 .

Comment: But that doesn't explain why you're using that `as` clause. That puts the reversed URL into a variable, which you've called `template`, instead of actually outputting it. Why do you want to do that? You're not using that variable anywhere.

Comment: (And note this would be a lot simpler if you put the Q outside of the capturing group in the URL, then you wouldn't need to add it manually to the ID).

Comment: Could you give me the code of this, I cannot understand how to put it outside the capturing URL. Thanks

Comment: And all I want is to concatenate "Q" with the {{ question.id }} and send this to the URL 'discussion:question'

Comment: Just `r'^Q(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)$'`. But note that wasn't your problem, it was the unnecessary use of `as`.

Comment: Yup I got it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong way in URL tag in html
You defined in html

```
{% url 'discussions:question'  with 'Q'|add:question.id as template %}
```

But {% url %} tag not use `with` in url templatetag. see in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url
So when you defined this tag in html that not render any url in html therefore when you click on html it opening same url.

You can use two ways

1)

```
{% with question.id|stringformat:'s' as question_id %}
    <a href="{% url 'discussions:question'  question_id='Q'|add:question_id  %}"></a>
{% endwith %}
```

2)

```
{% with question.id|stringformat:'s' as question_id %}
    {% url 'discussions:question'  question_id='Q'|add:question_id as template_url %}
    <a href="{{ template_url }} ></a>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering,
Method 1 gives the following error:
`Reverse for 'question' with keyword arguments '{'question_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['discussions/(?P<question_id>Q[0-9]+)$']
`
And method 2 is giving the same results as the problem  I have

Comment: And when  I try to print {{ template_url }} on the HTML page somewhere,I get blank as output.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand?

Comment: You mentioned in comment you got error "Reverse for 'question'" that is fix or not?

Comment: It is not a fix, since there should be no reverse error, I should have been redirected to website.come/discussions/Q5

Comment: Can you try to add static url manually for check like:
{% url 'discussions:question'  question_id='Q1'  %} put this in href and tell me output of <a>  tag if you are not getting again reverse error

Comment: Yes, I did it and it looks good. The output of anchor tag is `<a href=" /discussions/Q5"`

Comment: Even this works, `{% url 'discussions:question' question_id='Q'|add:'6' %}` and gives output as discussion/Q6

Comment: That means question.id not return any id in html. So try to print {{ question.id }} in loop.  like <a question-data="{{ question.id }}" </a> check  you are getting value of id or not

Comment: See my code in question, it is priting the question ID. The problem is with the add filter. It will take anything that is given to it in quotes, but it won't take question.id . I need to find a way to add 'Q' to question.id

Comment: "Q"|add:question.id here "Q" is string and question.id is integer So add templatetag not work with different type of data type. Read description of add template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#add